# How to estimate childhood mortality by different educational group using syncmrates?

Tags: stata

I am using `syncmrates` in Stata. Could you please tell me what command should I add to following command for getting mortality estimates by different educational group (suppose the variable for education is v008 which holds categories 1, 2 and 3). Can I get estimates for all the educational categories using a single command that could be added to following command?

```
syncmrates v008 b3 b7 [iw=v005]
```

Answer (score 1):

`syncmrates` is from SSC. It's always helpful to be told the provenance of community-contributed commands (see the Stata tag wiki).

Your example is from the help file, and it's implied that `v008` is (must be) a variable holding date of interview.

But given a further variable, say `education`, my reading of the help implies that you need to repeat the command with qualifiers

```
... if education == 1 

... if education == 2

... if education == 3
```

to get separate estimates.